# How to find the value of $\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20 + \cdots}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers, nested-radicals

Generally, I know how to calculate the square roots or cube roots, but I am confused in this question, not knowing how to do this:

$$\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20 + \cdots}}}$$

Note: Answer given in the key book is $5$.
Not allowed to use a calculator.

Comment: Your question title is wrong, I think. You want the value of the expression ($5$), not its square root ($\sqrt 5$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\displaystyle S=\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\cdots}}}$ which is definitely $>0$

$\displaystyle\implies S^2=20+S\iff S^2-S-20=0$

But we need to show the [convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322690/convergence-of-nested-radicals) of the sum

Comment: See also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Denote the corresponding value by $x$, then it satisfies the relation
$$x=\sqrt{20+x},$$
with the only positive solution $x=5$.

Comment: With the usual caveat that this only shows that *if* the limit exists, then it is equal to 5. (However, it seems quite easy to show that the sequence is monotone and bounded.)