# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{8 + ... \sqrt{2^{x}}}}}}}$.

Tags: proof-verification, radicals, nested-radicals

Let $s = \lim_{x \to \infty}{\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{8 + ... \sqrt{2^{x}}}}}}}$.

$$st = t\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{8 + ...}}}} = \sqrt{t^{2} + \sqrt{2t^{4} + \sqrt{4t^{8} + \sqrt{8t^{16} + ...}}}}$$

Let $2t^{4} = t^{2}$:

$$2t^{2} = 1$$
$$t^{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + ...}}}}$$

It can be shown that:

$$\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + ...}}}} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4x}}{2}$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$s = \frac{\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{6}}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Doubt: how did you "let $2t^4=t^2$"?

Comment: is $t$ arbitrary?

Comment: @JessePFrancis I want $t^{2} = 2t^{4} = 4t^{8} = 8t^{16} = ...$.

Comment: @Rise It is a constant to be found.

Comment: My calculator's telling me $s=1.78317$, which doesn't match what you have.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Yes, that is why I am here to ask. I do not know why this is, though.

Comment: Maybe it's because, when you simplify $st$, you do infinitely many operations at one. I agree that $st=\sqrt{t^2+t^2\sqrt{\dotsb}}$, and that $st=\sqrt{t^2+\sqrt{2t^4+t^4\sqrt{\dotsb}}}$, etc., but I'm not sure that you can assume that it's equal to what you posted above, since you're doing infinitely many operations.

Comment: The correct way to put it is: Find the limit for $n\to +\infty$ of $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{8 + ...+\sqrt{2^n}}}}}$

Comment: @Stef Ah, thank you. I was not sure.

Comment: If I'm reading this question correctly, it doesn't converge so the formal manipulations are meaningless.... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322690/convergence-of-nested-radicals

Comment: May be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/7216/45937

Comment: More blatant error: If $t=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, then $t^2=\frac12$, and $2t^4=\frac12$, but $4t^8=\frac14$. Your expression for $\frac s{\sqrt2}$ isn't composed entirely of $\frac12$s.

Comment: The coefficients _double_ each time, but you seem to have thought that they _square_ each time. I'm guessing that this is the main error, and that the infinitely many operations bit is probably fine.

Comment: @Myself I am pretty sure that it does converge...

Comment: @Myself They double each time, not square.

Comment: @Myself, Excel says terms beyond $x=8$ get very very close to $1.783166$ (I tried up to $x=20$), it should converge.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Ah yes I "miscompared" both sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, then $t^2=\frac12$, and $2t^4=\frac12$, but $4t^8=\frac14$. Your expression for $\frac s{\sqrt2}$ isn't composed entirely of $\frac12$s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to help me obtain a value of $t$ that would work, if one exists.

Comment: I don't think your plan would work, for any value of $t$.

Comment: I think that, if you do powers of $4$ instead of powers of $2$, the answer is equal to $2$. That is,$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{16+\sqrt{64+\dotsb}}}}=2$$

Comment: Ugh! Never mind -_-

Comment: @T.Golden [Relevant forum](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic168.html)