# Finding $\sqrt {6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...+\sqrt 6}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinity

For positive integer $n$, $$x_n=\sqrt {6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+...+\sqrt 6}}}$$ where $6$ is written $n$ times.

How can we find the $x _\infty$ ?

I coded a program any found that $x _\infty$ would be equal to $3$. So

> $$x _\infty =3$$

But I need to know how can we prove it. Or simply  how can we find $x _\infty$?

Comment: The sequence of partials is increasing. An easy induction shows it is bounded above, for example by $3$. So the limit exists. Now it is just a computation, $x=\sqrt{6+x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

If $y=\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\cdots}},y=\sqrt{n+y}$

$\implies y^2=n+y$ and $y\ge0$

For convergence see [Convergence of nested radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322690/convergence-of-nested-radicals) and [On Infinite Radicals](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2301294?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: See https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_11/papers/brian.pdf

Comment: Rigorously, one needs a seed value and a well-defined recurrence relationship.  Here, we can say the seed is $y_0$ with $y_k=\sqrt{n+y_{k-1}}$.  We arrive at the same conclusion, but I thought that this comment might be useful inasmuch as it codifies clearly the recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, it is clear all $x_n > 0$. Notice for any $n > 1$,
$$|3 - x_{n}| = |3 - \sqrt{6+x_{n-1}}| = \left|\frac{3-x_{n-1}}{3+\sqrt{6+x_{n-1}}}\right| < \frac13 |3-x_{n-1}|$$
This leads to for all $n > 0$,
$$|3-x_n| \le \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}|3 - x_1| = \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}|3-\sqrt{6}|$$
Since the RHS tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists and equals to $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $n \to \infty$, then we can write your expression as
$$y = \sqrt{6 + \sqrt{6  + \sqrt{6 \dots}}}$$
$$\implies y = \sqrt{6 + y}$$
$$\implies y^2 = 6 + y$$
$$\implies y^2 - y - 6 = 0$$
$$\implies y = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 24}}{2}$$
$$\implies y = \frac{1 \pm 5}{2} $$
$$\implies y = 3, -2$$
But we know that $y \ge 0$ since the RHS in of the original expression is $ > 0$
$$\implies y = 3$$
$$\text{Q.E.D.}$$